# AWS CodeDeploy Error "The revision size is too large. Its maximum size is 51200B"

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

**I am trying to deploy a Django web app on AWS.**

I use Jenkins for CI and CodeDeploy plugin to deploy my builds to AWS CodeDeploy. Jenkins works fine and I see "FINISHED:SUCCESS" after the build is finished.

But when I navigate to my AWS CodeDeploy console I see an error message:

"**The revision size is too large. Its maximum size is 51200B.**"

I have added the appspec.yml file to the root directory of my project, but it did not help.

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/wamsport/
permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu/wamsport
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
```

Comment: When you create deployment group manually in CD, and deploy it, do you get the same error? Or only when using Jenkins?

Comment: @Marcin Yes. There is a problem in deploying from S3 to CD actually :(

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention what type of CodeDeploy application is this (EC2, ECS). I am assuming it is ECS Blue/Green as this is where this error usually comes.

The limit for the revision size as mentioned in the error message is 51200B. This revision should usually be quite small, just including things like the appspec file, taskdef file and imageDetails or imageDefinitions file, well below the 51kb limit that is available.

Please check the contents of your zip file to confirm why the size is above 51kb. Whatever is in there, it is not required for ECS B/G.

### Edit1:

I just saw the AppSpec which is for EC2, so I belive you have selected the wrong Compute platform (Amazon ECS instead of EC2) when creating the CodeDeploy application.

Comment: What do you mean with it is not required for ECS B/G? And how do you deploy for example your python files in the blue server?

Comment: If you see the AppSpec file [1] for ECS B/G deployment via CodeDeploy, you will see it is just a specification file, there is no "code" as such. Your (python) code will be in a container image already pushed to a registry and the image will be referenced in an ECS Task definition - this task definition is then specified in the CodeDeploy AppSpec.

[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-ecs